# Django application with Docker compose, not able to run cron job. Getting "crontab: can't open 'appname': No such file or directory"

Tags: python, django, amazon-ec2, cron

This runs fine for me using `docker-compose up` locally. But when I run it on my EC2 (or locally) instance with `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up`,

and then run `docker-compose run --rm appname sh -c "python manage.py crontab show"`

I get `crontab: can't open 'appname': No such file or directory`,

followed by `Currently active jobs in crontab:`

Any ideas?